# .addClass in jquery datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to add a custom color to the disabled future dates in jQuery datepicker.

But when I try to add a custom class, the class is never added to the disabled dates.

Here is my code anyways:

```
<input type="text" id="picker"/>

$(function(){
    $("#picker").datepicker({
        maxDate: 0,
        beforeShow: function(input, inst){
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody > tr > td:has(span)').each(function (index) {
                        console.log($(this).closest("td"));

                        $(this).closest("td").addClass("red");
                    });
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/230crznm/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this CSS to your code:

```
td.ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-disabled span{
    background: red;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/230crznm/3)

No need for `beforeShow` if you are using this CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. Nice css solution. I only thought of jQuery solution.

Comment: @KarthikChintala No problem. Please upvote and mark this answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your css for disabled date.

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar td.ui-state-disabled span{
     color: red;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/230crznm/4/)**